# How to put color boxes on circuits

Tags: circuitikz, colorbox

I would like to put a color box around something basically this time is a circuit, I would also like to put a darker wire. Here es my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}  
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contenido} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{circuitikz} 

%Diodo

    \draw 
    [short, o-] to (0.3,0)
    ;
    \ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=0.4, bipoles/diode/width=0.4,} 
    \draw  
    (0.3,0)  node[below right = 4.15mm,align=center]{+} to[diode, a = $v_\gamma$, i = $i$]
  (3,0) node[below left = 4.15mm,align=center]{-} 
  ; 
  \draw 
  (3,0) [short,-o] to (3.2,0)
  ;  
  
 %Circuito abierto
  
\draw 
(5,0) [short, o-] to (6,0) 
to [-o,open] (8,0)  
; 
\draw 
(7.5,0) [short, o-] to (8.5,0)  
to [-o,open] (10.5,0) 
; 
\draw 
(5,0) node[above = 4mm, right = 1mm,align=center]{$\textcolor{red}{i}$ $\color{red}\longrightarrow$ } node[below = 10mm, right = 6mm,align=center]{$v<0\ $,  $i=0$} to [open, v =$v$ ] (8.5,0)
; 
%Corto circuito

\draw 
(10,0) [short, o-] to (11,0) 
to [-o,short] (13,0)  
; 
\draw 
(12.5,0) [short, o-] to (13.5,0)  
to [-o,short] (13.5,0) 
; 
\draw 
(10,0) node[above = 4mm, right = 1mm,align=center]{$i$ $\longrightarrow$ } node[below = 10mm, right = 6mm,align=center]{$i>0\ $,  $v=0$} to [open, v =$v$,red] (13.5,0)
; 


\end{circuitikz} 
\caption{Modelo Ideal}
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is more or less what i'm thinking it should look like.

[image]

I appreciate the help!

Comment: OP may like to add cut off voltage also to the diode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added some Ti*k*Z commands

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}  
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Contenido} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{circuitikz} 

%Diodo

    \draw 
    [short, o-] to (0.3,0)
    ;
    \ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=0.4, bipoles/diode/width=0.4,} 
    \draw  
    (0.3,0)  node[below right = 4.15mm,align=center]{+} to[diode, a = $v_\gamma$, i = $i$]
  (3,0) node[below left = 4.15mm,align=center]{-} 
  ; 
  \draw 
  (3,0) [short,-o] to (3.2,0)
  ;  

 %Circuito abierto

\fill[cyan!20] (5.8,-.2) rectangle (7.7,.2);
\draw 
(5,0) [short, o-] to (6,0) 
to [-o,open] (8,0)  
; 
\draw 
(7.5,0) [short, o-] to (8.5,0)  
to [-o,open] (10.5,0) 
; 
\draw 
(5,0) node[above = 4mm, right = 1mm,align=center]{$\textcolor{red}{i}$ $\color{red}\longrightarrow$ } node[below = 10mm, right = 6mm,align=center]{$v<0\ $,  $i=0$} to [open, v =$v$ ] (8.5,0)
; 
%Corto circuito

\fill[cyan!20] (10.8,-.2) rectangle (12.7,.2);
\draw[ultra thick] (11,0) -- (12.5,0);
\draw 
(10,0) [short, o-] to (11,0) 
to [-o,short] (12.5,0)  
; 
\draw 
(12.5,0) [short, o-] to (13.5,0)  
to [-o,short] (13.5,0) 
; 
\draw 
(10,0) node[above = 4mm, right = 1mm,align=center]{$i$ $\longrightarrow$ } node[below = 10mm, right = 6mm,align=center]{$i>0\ $,  $v=0$} to [open, v =$v$,red] (13.5,0)
; 


\end{circuitikz} 
\caption{Modelo Ideal}
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here I focus on adding the background rectangles, not on improving the code. I keep many things very explicit to make it easier to understand what's going on. Your code can be simplified a lot, and my additions can be made more efficient at the expense of understandability.

You can name some coordinates and fit them in rectangular nodes on the background layer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{circuitikz} 

%Diodo

    \draw 
    [short, o-] to (0.3,0)
    ;
    \ctikzset{bipoles/diode/height=0.4, bipoles/diode/width=0.4,} 
    \draw  
    (0.3,0)  node[below right = 4.15mm,align=center]{+} to[diode, a = $v_\gamma$, i = $i$]
  (3,0) node[below left = 4.15mm,align=center]{-} 
  ; 
  \draw 
  (3,0) [short,-o] to (3.2,0)
  ;  

 %Circuito abierto

\draw 
(5,0) [short, o-] to (6,0)coordinate(L1) to [-o,open] (8,0)  
; 
\draw 
(7.5,0) coordinate(R1)[short, o-] to (8.5,0)  
to [-o,open] (10.5,0) 
; 
\draw 
(5,0) node[above = 4mm, right = 1mm,align=center]{$\textcolor{red}{i}$
$\color{red}\longrightarrow$ } node[below = 10mm, right =
6mm,align=center]{$v<0\ $,  $i=0$} to [open, v =$v$ ] (8.5,0)
; 
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \node[fit=(L1)(R1),fill=blue!10,inner xsep=1.5mm,inner ysep=2mm]{};
\end{scope}
%Corto circuito

\draw 
(10,0) [short, o-] to (11,0) coordinate(L2)
to [-o,short] (13,0)  
; 
\draw 
(12.5,0) coordinate(R2) [short, o-] to (13.5,0)  
to [-o,short] (13.5,0) 
; 
\draw 
(10,0) node[above = 4mm, right = 1mm,align=center]{$i$ $\longrightarrow$ } node[below = 10mm, right = 6mm,align=center]{$i>0\ $,  $v=0$} to [open, v =$v$,red] (13.5,0)
; 

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \node[fit=(L2)(R2),fill=blue!10,inner xsep=1.5mm,inner ysep=2mm]{};
\end{scope}
\end{circuitikz} 
\caption{Modelo Ideal.}
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for the sake of knowledge, can you please show me what improvements would you make on my code? I know my code is a little bit complecated but I was the only way a manage to make it work, I'm still learning how to use this itz tool.

Comment: @JulioOrtegón Please ask the OP of the accepted answer. You seem to be more comfortable with their style, which is of course fine, but this means you will be better off learning from them.